# Is it possible to switch to Kerberos only Windows domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, windows, kerberos

Is it possible to configure both Windows servers and workstations (Windows 7) to use only Kerberos for authentication and not use NTLM for authentication within the Domain?

I was told that Kerberos authentication fails if the target system is accessed via IP address.

Any success or failure stories out there?

Answer (score 2):

here's a recent article on this http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/02/02/purging-old-nt-security-protocols.aspx

sorry to link bomb and run but this does contain the answer

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the link. Unfortunately it only discusses if LM/NTLM is in use, but not if Kerberos only domain is possible.

Comment: this statement from the msft guy in the blog "No, because you cannot configure a server to ignore NTLMv2." means that it won't ignore lmv2 it just might not use it, which at that point would me kerberos only.

Comment: @tony_roth Thanks for pointing that out. One of the reasons I'm looking into this is to prevent replay attacks or password hash cracking. If the NTLMv2 still gets sent along, then that's bad.

Comment: also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560653(WS.10).aspx will give you further info if in a win7+ enviro.  Also pw hash hacking is not completely solved by kerberos, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Reviewing the above articles, it is my understanding then that you can not force a server to not do NTLMv2 authentication. I understand that given the opportunity, Kerberos will be negotiated as the stronger protocol.